# Error while parsing a date string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a start date as string "20160812 17:45:36" [Format: YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS].

Wanted to add 1 day to the date (C#), hence output should be "20160813 17:45:36".

```
string startDate = "20160812 17:45:36";
try
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
        startDate, 
        "YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
catch(Exception excep) 
{
    throw excep;
}
```

I am getting below error while executing above code,

**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: Your format string is **not** valid. Try `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Don't make up your own format strings and expect them to work. See [MSDN: Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: correct formats can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx . 2 minutes research would have told you this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your datetime format

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
        startDate, 
        "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```